# Why is LLC.exe missing in LLVM windows?

Tags: clang, emscripten, llc

I've been trying to use emscripten to build C into WASM and Javascript. Emscripten requires clang so I installed it but then it says "emcc: error: llc executable not found at `C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\llc.exe`" when running emcc and em++. Is there a reason that LLC.exe is missing in the windows version? If so how do I get it.

Comment: What is *it* that is saying that, and what is the **exact, complete error message** that you're getting? Don't paraphrase, don't guess - provide the **exact, complete message**.

Comment: emcc: error: llc executable not found at `C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\llc.exe` I checked the folder and the LLC.exe file is missing

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide the information there, where it belongs, not bury it in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

llc is a developer tool. If you want it, build it from llvm-project source. This is/will not included in the release binary.

Comment: Isn't the entirety of llvm a "developer tool", though? LLVM IR is an important part of the toolset, so I find this distinction to be somewhat arbitrary. Alas.